# How to make spotify play all songs in the search results

Tags: spotify

On the Windows desktop version of Spotify, when you search and start playing one song in the search results, Spotify will play all the subsequent songs in the search results when the song ends. It even shuffles the results if you have shuffle turned on. The Android app used to have this function as well, but it appears it was removed because it annoyed people sometime in 2018 (really, if you just want the one song, add it to the queue and skip once; it's not hard). Is there a workaround to still have this feature? Someone on the Spotify forums claimed that Spotify now creates a playlist based on search results:

> The overhaul follows Spotify’s recent update to song search; now when you search for a song with a common name, Spotify will create a playlist, an actual list, based around the song instead of playing every version of that searched song in order.
>   You can learn more by reading this blog post and this article of what's new with Spotify Premium.

The blog post in question was vauge and had no instances of the word "playlist" on the page, and the article concerned something about the artists radio, so I'm going to assume that person has no idea what they're talking about, but it's my only lead so I posted it in case someone can clarify this feature

The main question is: **Is it possible, in any way, to make the Spotify android app play all the songs in the search results?**